# Adding command-line in cmd

Tags: python, cmd, command-line

Is there any way to create a command on Command Prompt like I want to create a command named createdirectory(I know there is an existing command for that but take this as an example) . when i execute the command "createdirectory" it will run a python file. I want it in such a way that i can run this command from anywhere any disk volume or any folder.

If you know anything  then please post your answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Open a Windows [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) window, run `help` and look on the incomplete list of [Windows commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) with brief description. There is also [SS64.com - A-Z index of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/). There can be used a macro defined with __DOSKEY__ with usage help output on running `doskey /?` or a batch file called with one or more argument strings. The help output on running `call /?` explains how to reference the arguments.

Comment: Please take a look on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) The usage of one or more batch files require to have the batch files in a directory of which path is added to __system__ or __user__ `Path` whereby the latter is most likely better in this case. Example: `@python.exe "C:\Full Path To\PythonScript.py" %*` whereby `python.exe` could be also specified with full path enclosed in `"` for most efficient (=fastest) execution.

Answer (score 1):

Shell commands are basically either aliases or programs stored on disk. You can write your programs put them in some directory and add that directory path to the shell's `PATH` variable.

Let's say you have a program called `create.py` which creates the directories. You can follow these two ways to make them available as command on a shell

Assume `create.py` is present in `/home/bob/scripts` directory

### Create a wrapper script

1. Create a file called `createDirectory` with below content in `/home/bob/scripts`

   ```bash
   python /home/bob/scripts/create.py $*
   ```
2. Add `/home/bob/scripts` to the `PATH`

   ```bash
   export PATH="$PATH:/home/bob/scripts"
   ```

### Using aliases

1. Run the alias command

   ```bash
   alias createDirectory="python /home/bob/scripts/create.py"
   ```

### Usage

```bash
createDirectory <whatever> <arguments> <your> <program> <expects>
```

**NOTE**: You can add this alias command and export command to ~/.bashrc file so that it is run when you start a shell

Comment: Pritam was not very clear for which operating system the non-programming help is needed. But the usage of the tag [cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cmd/info) is an indication for me that a __Windows__ *Command Prompt* solution is wanted and __not__ a Linux/Max __shell__ interpreter solution.

Comment: Yes I want it in command promt which is in windows